# C# XSD schema - how to get main properties values?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have the XSD schema definition loaded (`XDocument` variable type) I can't figure out how to get the `someProperty` value. Any ideas ?

```
<xsd:form-definition xmlns:xsd="http://url/lorem.xsd"
     xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     ...
     someProperty="ABC">
 ...
</xsd:form-definition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple with LINQ to XML:

```
var attributes = (from n in xml.Root.Attributes("someProperty")
                        select n.Value).ToList();
```